# I keep getting this error with my multiline list merger

Tags: python, list, multiline

```
    lista = ['Add', 'Append']
    listb = []
    listc = []
    listd = ['Delete']
    liste = []
    listf = []
    listg = []
    listh = []
    listi = []
    listj = []
    listk = []
    listl = []
    listm = []
    listn = []
    listo = []
    listp = []
    listq = []
    listr = []
    lists = []
    listt = []
    listu = []
    listv = []
    listw = []
    listx = []
    listy = []
    listz = []
    listabc123 = lista + listb + listc + listd + liste + listf + listg +                  listh + listi + listj # <---All this is on same line as listabc123 
    listabc123 = listabc123 + listk + listl + listm + listn + listo + listp + listq + listr # <---All this is on same line as listabc123 
    listabc123 = listabc123 + lists + listt + listu + listv + listw + listx + listy + listz # <---All this is on same line as listabc123
```

Before I wrote the last attempt shown above I tried using \ for each lin and () around all the lists I wanted to combine.

When run it take a long time (I never waited longer than 5 minutes before I pressed Enter in idle) Then I get this error.

IDLE internal error in runcode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 339, in putmessage
    r, w, x = select.select([], [self.sock], [])
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 240, in asyncqueue
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 342, in putmessage
    raise OSError("socket no longer exists")
OSError: socket no longer exists

Thanks for taking time to read and would appreciate any help given. Thanks in advance.

PS Using python 3.7

Comment: Why are you doing this?  What are you trying to do?  Your error is also completely unrelated to the code you have posted.

Comment: Firstly, the error you mentioned is not from the code you provided. Secondly, why are you having so many lists? There is a lot which is needed to be improved in this, but I don't see any error in the code

Comment: Multi-line list merger ? Please... At least use a for loop to iterate over the lists and combine them.

Comment: I want to eventually put commands for a program into list. Then put a number by each command in list so that I can execute each command.

Comment: Why so many lists, just because, I want to keep it organized. All A commands in lista and so on.

Comment: I know what your saying about loop. Just not there in knowledge yet on how to do it. I know I can make one list , have it sort it. Just went this direction and am not sure why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Can't add comments, but I'll at least try to add some insight here. If I make a similar bit of code:

```
a = ["one" , "two"]
b = ["three"]
c = []
d = ["four"]
e = []
combined = a + b + c + d + e
```

This isn't the best practice for combining lists (as suggested in the comments), but running this in a python shell shouldn't produce any errors. The error you are getting is a Cython error (link to package referenced: [rpc.py](http://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/rpc.py)

Again, I can't post comments, but are you trying to connect to a server or something of the like? (ie: is this your full code) If not, some insight into what you are connecting to or the code used to connect would be helpful.

It looks like you've closed a connection and are trying to connect to it again without opening it, but that's just a guess from your error.

Comment: Thanks , actually not trying to connect to anything. Yes this is all my code. I am trying to learn python for fun. Haven't created a file, used openpyxl that day. 3.7 was a fresh install when I started to get those type of errors in 3.6. Since I posted the question , went back and uninstalled old versions of python I had. I am at the first few pages of the tutorial. I guess it could be my firewall, but nothing I have messed with should have tried to connect to anything and my firewall hasn't  upped its count on threats blocked.

Comment: Looks like you found your answer (looking at the answer you added below). Python can get weird when you install multiple instances of it. Have you tried using Anaconda (if you're looking at getting different versions of python)?  Best of luck with learning Python, it's pretty fun to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

It seems deleting all old versions of python I had and doing a fresh install fixed my Errors.